# Ring homomorphism $\pi : \mathbb{Z}_b \to \mathbb{Z}_a$ if $a | b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

> Is the map
>
> $$\pi : \mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z},$$
>   where $\pi([k]_b) = [k]_a$ and $a|b$, a ring homomorphism?

I ask because in a set of notes I read, it was given that the map

$$\pi : \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$$

is a ring homomorphism since $p|p^n$, given by $\pi([a]_{p^n}) = [a]_p$.

I'm somewhat confused as to why this is the case. Can we simply map the elements of $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ to their corresponding residue classes in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$? What goes wrong if $a \nmid b$? It seems as if $[1]_b$ doesn't map to $[1]_a$ if we lack this condition but I'm not sure..

Comment: if $a\not\mid b$ then if $[j]_b=[k]_b$ it is not necessarily true that $[j]_a=[k]_a$ - that is, the function $\pi$ is not well-defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the third isomorphism theorem, since $a|b$ we have $(a)\supseteq (b)$ hence

> $$\Bbb Z/(a)\cong\Bbb Z/(b)\bigg/(a)/(b)$$

So the reduction map is a well-defined ring map.

If there is no division then there is no inclusion of ideals, so there is no map down since the fourth isomorphism theorem tells you that the **only** ideals of $\Bbb Z/(n)$ are the $(m)/(n)$ with $m|n$ since this is the only case where $(m)\supseteq (n)$.

Answer (score 1):

The function $\pi$ is well-defined if any only if $a\mid b$.

If $a\mid b$ and $[j]_b=[k]_b$ then $b\mid j-k$ and hence $a\mid j-k$, so $[j]_a=[k]_a$. So $\pi$ is a well-defined map.

On the other hand, if $a\not\mid b$ then $[0]_b=[b]_b$ but $[0]_a\neq [b]_a$, so $\pi$ is not a well-defined map.

Answer (score 0):

Let R be a ring and let $I,J \subseteq R$ be ideals in $R$

For a map $R/I \to R/J$ which sends $r + I \to r + J$ to be well-defined we need that whenever $r_1 + \ I = r_2 + I$, then $r_1 + J = r_2 + J$, i.e that the value is independent of the choice of representative for the element you are evaluating. This is equivalent to saying that whenever $r_2 - r_1 \in I$, then $r_2 - r_1 \in J$, which in turn is equivalent to $I \subseteq J$.

In your example $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and $I = p^n\mathbb{Z} \subseteq p\mathbb{Z} = J$.

Also, any possible map $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ which sends the identity to the identity must be given as above.